# my_name is not authorized to perform: events:ListRules on resource: arn:aws:events:ap-south-1:account_numbre:rule/* while using code pipline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

i am using codepipline with minimum permission that are managed by admin.

i am getting this error my_name is not authorized to perform: events:ListRules on resource: arn:aws:events:ap-south-1:account_numbre:rule/* while using codepipline

I have full permission for codedeploy,codebuild,codepipline,cloudwatch,ec2,ECS,S3.

although i can create pipline and when i edit the pipline its giving me the error even i can not delete the pipline.

please suggest if any other permission needed.

Comment: Which policy are you using for `Cloudwatch` full access?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch and EventBridge need different permission as they are separated. I think you need to add `events` to your policy.

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
   "events:*",
    ...
 ]
```

For now just try with the wildcard `*` to see if it is working, later on adjust the actions to give the minimum necessary permission.

If not, could you please post your policy template?